# Column and remove blank space in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2012 I want show hide column and remove blank space.

Following 3 tables grid actually represent one grid. How can I suppress column and remove blank space like following table :

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
  a    df  we   df
  sdf   df  df  df


COL1  COL3 COL4
     a    we   df
    sdf   df  df

 COL1  COL4
   a    df
  sdf   df
```

Comment: use crosstab for that

Comment: What is the alignment for each field? (right, left or center)

Comment: col1,col2,col3,col4 are database fields

Comment: couldn't find any blank space in your example... also on what basis you want to suppress the column?

Comment: I mean if user select col1,col2,col4 from drop down these column only show